# Getting the selected option in Javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Self teaching Node.js and Javascript stuff. I have in the form in my HTML and select, drop down menu option. How do I get the index of the selected value?

So far im trying this:

```
var e = req.body.boolean_choice;
boolChoice = e.selectedIndex;
```

I have the `req.body` working for getting the inputted values in a text box, but it tells me `selectedIndex` is not a thing. So then I tried:

```
var e = req.body.boolean_choice
```

to see what that gave and it just gave `undefined`.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000" method="POST">
Form:<br>
<br>
<br>
Text Box 1: <input type="text" name="tb1"  size="35" placeholder="&quot;@10SadioMane&quot; OR &quot;#Mane&quot;">
<br>
<br>
<select id="choice" name="choice">
  <option value="OR">OR</option>
  <option value="AND">AND</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML ?

Comment: Use selection option value as an array of object with index and value like [{"id":1, "name":"test"}, ... ], and in select function call send the id rather than   name.

Comment: maybe this old question can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: @NathanP. I've just added the HTML, it's a very basic form

Comment: @DominicReeve your select name is *choice*, not *boolean_choice*

Comment: @NathanP. Thank you so much! I can't believe I had missed that! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Form submitting will pass only `value` property of selection. 
Also use debugger in IDE that you use, to explore `req.body`, instead of trying to guess what's there.

Comment: or do `console.log(req.body)` to view it in the console running node

Comment: im not guessing at what is there, I've used `req.body.tb1` which returns the input of that text box. So I assumed the logic would be the same for this.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to help.

*First of all get the **Selected option DOM element***

```
var el = document.querySelector('#choice option:selected');
```

ibn your case it will be 
    req.body.querySelector('#choice option:selected');

Now logic is to iterate to the previous siblings in the chain till you reach to the top.

```
var index = 0; 
while( el.previousSibling ! == null){
el = el.previousSibling;
index +=1;
}
console.log(index);
```

Comment: Since he using `req.body` I suppose he need index on server side.

Comment: `option:selected` is not a valid selector, valid for jQuery